# How do I align a flex div to the center and should completely fit in the screen, irrespective of the device screen width?

Tags: html

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="bg-image"></div>

<div class="flex-container">
        <div class="left arrow">
            <button class="btn" style="background-color: azure; border: 2px solid black;" id="left"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-text" id="first_div">
            <h4><u>Newspaper particulars</u><i class="fa fa-sign-out" style="float: right; cursor: pointer;"></i></h4><br>
            <ul>
                <li><label for="date">Select date</label><br></li>
                <input type="date" id="date" name="date" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"><br><br>
                <li><label for="unit">Select division</label><br></li>
                <select name="unit" id="unit" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                    <option value="default" id="default">Click to select</option>
                    <option value="HQ">HQ</option>
                </select><br><br>
                <li><label for="cat">Select news category</label><br></li>
                <div id="cat" style="border: 2px solid white; padding: 5px;">
                    <input type="radio" id="newspaper" name="category" value="News paper">
                    <label for="newspaper">News paper</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="newsportal" name="category" value="News portal">
                    <label for="newsportal">News portal</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="socialmedia" name="category" value="Social media">
                    <label for="socialmedia">Social media</label>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="para" id="second_div">
            <div class="container">
                <span id="preview_text" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; color: red;">Image preview</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right arrow">
            <button class="btn" style="background-color: azure; border: 2px solid black;" id="right"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div id="but">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("/background.jpg");
  
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 
  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
.left.arrow{
  /* margin-top: 30%; */
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
  height: fit-content;
}
.right.arrow{
  /* margin-top: 30%; */
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
  height: fit-content;
}
.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 20px;
  height: fit-content;
}
.para{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.329); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-container {
display: flex;
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
position:fixed;
left: 20%;
margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
}
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
#preview_text{
line-height: 500px;
}
#but{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute; 
  top:100%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

My issue is that the `flex` div is never in the center of the screen no matter how much I modify the CSS. And sometimes when I try to view the html page in a mobile screen one of the divs inside the `flex` div becomes longer than the other. My requirement is that both the divs inside the `flex` div should be of equal heights on all times. And the whole `flex` div should be in the center of the screen.

The `but` div should be below the `flex` div and should be in the center respective to the `flex` div. The `left arrow` and `right arrow` divs should also be in the center (also respective to the `flex` div). This is a pictorial representation of what I want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skq5H.png)

How do I proceed? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the `but` div I think is better to move it one level up and create a new container. So the `div` can be positioned without using absolute.

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="but">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

As you are using a div for the background, You need to keep `position: fixed` here. Now to center the `but` you can use `align-self` because using `align-items` in the container will make the children to shrink later.

```css
#but {
  align-self: center;
}
```

To make all `flex-container` children same height lets remove all height properties since that is the default behavior of flex-box (when in row direction). And to make `para` and `bg-text` divs same width lets use `flex: 1`. This will make them grow to the same size as long as it has enough space.

```css
.left.arrow {
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right.arrow {
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

.para {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.329);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}
```

It looks like you want to center the `preview_text`. Lets use flex-box again.

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#preview_text {
  /* line-height: 500px; */
}
```

For now the `flex-container` is using full width. To limit it you can use a fixed margin or fixed width. Using percentage for this will create large margins on small screens unless you put different values for different screen sizes (using media queries or the calc and min/max functions). Let's use a fixed width and `margin: auto` to keep it centralized.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Final result:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("/background.jpg");
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */

.left.arrow {
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right.arrow {
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1
}

.para {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.329);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#preview_text {
  /* line-height: 500px; */
}

#but {
  align-self: center;
}

.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-image"></div>
  <div class="outer-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="left arrow">
        <button class="btn" style="background-color: azure; border: 2px solid black;" id="left"><i
             class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-text" id="first_div">
        <h4><u>Newspaper particulars</u><i class="fa fa-sign-out" style="float: right; cursor: pointer;"></i></h4><br>
        <ul>
          <li><label for="date">Select date</label><br></li>
          <input type="date" id="date" name="date" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"><br><br>
          <li><label for="unit">Select division</label><br></li>
          <select name="unit" id="unit" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
            <option value="default" id="default">Click to select</option>
            <option value="HQ">HQ</option>
          </select><br><br>
          <li><label for="cat">Select news category</label><br></li>
          <div id="cat" style="border: 2px solid white; padding: 5px;">
            <input type="radio" id="newspaper" name="category" value="News paper">
            <label for="newspaper">News paper</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="newsportal" name="category" value="News portal">
            <label for="newsportal">News portal</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="socialmedia" name="category" value="Social media">
            <label for="socialmedia">Social media</label>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="para" id="second_div">
        <div class="container">
          <span id="preview_text" style="color: red;">Image preview</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right arrow">
        <button class="btn" style="background-color: azure; border: 2px solid black;" id="right"><i
             class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="but">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. Just a small thing, I changed the position of the `outer-container` from `fixed` to `absolute` otherwise the `but` div wasn't even visible in the screen.